# SSL_write() seems to close connection

Tags: c, networking, ssl, openssl

I try to implement a multithreaded Client-Server Application in C. Here is my connection specific code:

Server:

```
SSL_load_error_strings();
SSL_library_init();
OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
if((ctx->ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_server_method())) == NULL) {
  tproxy_error_die("unable to initialize SSLv3 methods", 1);
}
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx->ssl_ctx, SSL_OP_ALL);
SSL_CTX_set_timeout(ctx->ssl_ctx, 300);
if(!SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ctx->ssl_ctx, ctx->cert_bundle)) {
  tproxy_error_die("unable to read certificate bundle file", 1);
}
if(strlen(ctx->key_file_pw)) {
  SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(ctx->ssl_ctx, private_key_pass_callback);
  SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata(ctx->ssl_ctx, (void *)ctx);
}
if(!SSL_CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey_file(ctx->ssl_ctx, ctx->key_file, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)) {
  tproxy_error_die("unable to read key file", 1);
}
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx->ssl_ctx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);
SSL_CTX_set_info_callback(ctx->ssl_ctx, apps_ssl_info_callback);
[...]
con->sock = accept(ctx->socket[i], (struct sockaddr *)&in_socket, &s_size);
/* make the accepted socket non-blocking */
if(ioctl(con->sock, FIONBIO, (char *)&enable) < 0) {
  tproxy_error_die("cannot set socket flags", 1);
}
/* create a new SSL context to handle the connection with the peer */
con->ssl = SSL_new(ctx->ssl_ctx);
SSL_set_mode(con->ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY | SSL_MODE_ENABLE_PARTIAL_WRITE);

/* complete ssl connection */
con->sbio = BIO_new_socket(con->sock, BIO_NOCLOSE);
SSL_set_bio(con->ssl, con->sbio, con->sbio);
/* set chipher */
if (SSL_set_cipher_list(con->ssl,"AES128-SHA") <= 0) {
  tproxy_error_die("unable to set chipher", 1);
}
/* do not require a valid client certificate */
SSL_set_verify(con->ssl, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);
```

Later I read and write with SSL_read() and SSL_write() (honoring that -1 as a return code has to result in evaluating SSL_get_error() and my result in repeating the same function in my code).

However the application handshake (a few bytes exchanged between client and server) works like a charm. But once the Server sends more than 4 bytes (after application handshake) to the client, the client seems to drop the connection (SSL_read() returns 0) even if the SSL_write on the Server returned exact the amount of bytes I sent (SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL is the SSL error and the system errno stays 0). The socket was not closed.

Does anyone has a clue - maybe how to debug more an openssl application?

Here is the output of the msg_callback from the Client:

```
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read server hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read server session ticket A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server session ticket A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read finished A
```

---> here it closes

Here is the output of the msg_callback from the Server:

```
SSL_accept:before/accept initialization
SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client hello B
SSL_accept:SSLv3 read client hello B
SSL_accept:SSLv3 write server hello A
SSL_accept:SSLv3 write certificate A
SSL_accept:SSLv3 write server done A
SSL_accept:SSLv3 flush data
SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client certificate A
SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client certificate A
SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client certificate A
SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client certificate A
SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client certificate A
SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client certificate A
SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client certificate A
SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client certificate A
SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client certificate A
SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client certificate A
SSL_accept:SSLv3 read client key exchange A
SSL_accept:SSLv3 read finished A
SSL_accept:SSLv3 write session ticket A
SSL_accept:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
SSL_accept:SSLv3 write finished A
SSL_accept:SSLv3 flush data
```

---> here it closes

The tcpdump shows me, that che tcp-fin comes from the client first. But if the server doesn´t sent the "killing" 5 bytes the client can infinitely send application keepalive messages over the ssl link.

In what condition is SSL_write able to alert the other side in such a way and how may I debug this behaviour?

Comment: Just an observation... If you want TLS 1.0 and above, use `SSLv23_server_method` and then remove SSL protocols with `SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2` and `SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3`.

Comment: What is the return value from `SSL_get_error()`? Is it `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` or `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`? See https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_get_error.html for details.